# Linux awk - How to convert date format : Wed 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT to Wed 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 +02:00?

Tags: datetime, awk, date-format, timezone-offset

Ive been trying to convert that date format for hours now. I want to get rif off the GMT and replace with my time zone which is +02:00

```
awk -F, -v currentDate=`TZ="Europe/Paris" date -d  "23 hours ago" +%s`'{OFS=",";"date -d" $1" +%s"
```

with $1 = Wed 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT

I keep getting the same input as ouput, it seems its ignoring the TZ

My current timezone is +2h, so either appending that to the date in place of the GMT or convert the date to localtime.

Expected result = `Wed 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52+02:00` or `Wed 20 Apr 2018 21:56:52`

Comment: I think one of the things that confuses me about this question is, you seem to be saying that you want to change the timezone, but not leave the date the same.  In other words, you don't want to get the same actual time in your time zone, you want to fix only the time zone of the input.   Right?  That doesn't require any date manipulation - just `sed 's/ GMT/+02:00/` , right?  I don't follow what `23 hours ago` has to do with anything.

Comment: You want to insert a comma and replace `GMT` with `+2:00`?

Comment: That script won't produce **any** output except a syntax error. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with a minimal complete script and concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: When you do these commands by themselves: `date -d  "23 hours ago" +%s` and `TZ="Europe/Paris" date -d  "23 hours ago" +%s`, what do you see?

Comment: Basically im retrieving a GMT date and would like to convert it to my local time using my current timezone (+02:00). I cant do  ```sed s/ GMT/+02:00/```  since the timezone is changing. But i think either converting it to my local time or appending my time zone will be fine

Comment: Exactly it seems its ignoring the timezome or maybe im not using it the right way, but have tried a combination of single/double quote, itsnt working

Comment: `TZ="Europe/Paris" date -d  "23 hours ago" +%s` => `1624996341`

Comment: `date -d  "23 hours ago" +%s` => 1624996463

Answer (score 1):

```
$ TZ="Europe/Paris" awk 'BEGIN{"date -d \"Wed 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT\"" | getline; print}'
Fri Apr 20 21:56:52 CEST 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need awk in this case :

```
~$ set - "Wed 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT"
~$ echo "$1"
Wed 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT
~$ TZ=Europe/Paris date -d "$1" +"%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%:z"
Fri 20 Apr 2018 21:56:52+02:00
~$ TZ=Europe/Paris date -d "$1" +"%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"
Fri 20 Apr 2018 21:56:52
```

Answer (score 0):

### Wed 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT was Friday

Your date-time string, `Wed 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT` is wrong as `20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT` was not Wednesday; it was Friday.

### Fri 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT = Fri 20 Apr 2018 21:56:52+02:00

The expected result you have mentioned in the question is confusing because `Fri 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT` = `Fri 20 Apr 2018 21:56:52+02:00`. The calculation is simple: subtract the offset value from the date-time to get the equivalent GMT (or UTC) date-time.

Since you have tagged the question with [java](/questions/tagged/java), given below is the solution using Java:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Fri 20 Apr 2018 19:56:52 GMT";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE d MMM u H:m:s O", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odtGmt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtfInput);
        OffsetDateTime odtOffsetTwoHrs = odtGmt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+02:00"));
        System.out.println(odtOffsetTwoHrs);

        // Output in a custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE d MMM u H:m:sXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(odtOffsetTwoHrs.format(dtfOutput));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2018-04-20T21:56:52+02:00
Fri 20 Apr 2018 21:56:52+02:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/sOkWa1)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.